# Webpack output UMD library with CamelCase and spinal-case name

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

How do I configure Webpack to create UMD bundle, so that package name for AMD and CommonJS will be named in lowercase (spinal-case), and for global context will have CamelCase name?

For example I expect my bundle to start with

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory(require("dependency"));
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("my-library", ["dependency"], factory);           // spinal-case
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["my-library"] = factory(require("dependency"));  // spinal-case
    else
        root["MyLibrary"] = factory(root["dependency"]);         // CamelCase
})...
```

This is how it looks in ReactDOM:

```
(function(f) {
  // CommonJS
  if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
    module.exports = f(require('react'));

  // RequireJS
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(['react'], f);

  // <script>
  } else {
    var g;
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      g = window;
    } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
      g = global;
    } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
      g = self;
    } else {
      // works providing we're not in "use strict";
      // needed for Java 8 Nashorn
      // see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3037
      g = this;
    }
    g.ReactDOM = f(g.React);
  }
})(function(React)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should have the property `umdNamedDefine` set to `true`. This is what my `output` block commonly looks like when I do a UMD wrapped library. I will use an example from an npm package that I currently have as it will be the most illustrative:

```
output: {
    path: './lib',
    filename: 'dom-regex.js',
    library: 'DomRegex',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
},
```

Given that my npm package is named `dom-regex` in the `package.json`, this allows me to use my packages in the following ways:

**ES6:**

```
import DomRegex from 'dom-regex';
```

**RequireJS**

```
var DomRegex = require('dom-regex');
```

**On the window: (if the file is exposed directly to the window)**

```
window.DomRegex
```

---

What the name is exported as in the UMD wrapped section isn't as important as what you name it when you import it. Using `dom-regex` as an example, even if I had it locally in my project (not in node_modules), and the filename was `dom-regex.js`, I could still do all the previous examples, because it is UMD wrapped:

You're welcome to explore the [repo for dom-regex](https://github.com/kevinokerlund/dom-regex) and test download the package to see how this works.

Comment: As an example, when using ES6 you do `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom;', `var ReactDOM = require('react');' with RequireJS and when simply adding script to a file, you just call `ReactDOM` (`window.ReactDOM`). See ReactJS bundle https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js

Comment: @AlexanderShutov, I've updated my answer with a better example, and a repo you can explore / experiment with.

Comment: Finally to get what I need I had to remove `umdDefineName`, so that AMD and CommonJS section go without name. CommonJS is left by Webpack for some reason, but luckily is ignored when importing in Webpack or Rollup. Finally, look, [how React team do it](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/046f7448d7224da5b33441248a32a319a6464bc5/grunt/config/browserify.js#L98).